# How to add an hour value in excell file with Apache POI?

Tags: java, input, apache-poi, file-extension, hour

I would really like to know can we add an hour value in excel with Simple Date Format.When i usually try to import an hour value it results to wrong input to excel...so i am in a dead-end.Any help...much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a cell with a time based format applied to it, eg `HH:MM`, and you want to add an hour

Dates in Excel are stored as integer days since 1st Jan 1900 or 1904 (don't ask...), and times are the fractions of a day within that

So, if you want to add 1 hour to the value in cell A1, you'd do

```
CellReference ref = new CellReference("A1");
Row row = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
if (row == null) throw new Exception("Row empty");
Cell cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
if (cell == null) throw new Exeeption("Cell empty");
cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue() + (1.0/24));
```

Comment: i dont want to add 1 hour to the value of A1 i just want to write in an excell cell that will be of an hour cell style

Comment: Just do that then! I'm not following what your problem is

Comment: I just want you to show me a way to create date cells in excel.Not to just add a Date in  in a cell of "custom" style.I want to add a date in a "date" style cell